# Cell is formula? In googlescript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to do an action if the selected cell is formula, how do I do?

Some command like isformula() of Google Sheets.

Ex.:
if (cell == "formula"?) {make something}
else {make something}

Comment: The `gas` tag is for the GNU assembler. Please edit your questions with appropriate tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[image]google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) function [`getFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormula()) may be handy:

> *getFormula()*
>
> **Output.** String
>
> Returns the formula (A1 notation) for the top-left cell of the range,
>   or an empty string if the cell is empty or doesn't contain a formula.

Please try:

```
if (range.getFormula().substring(0, 1) === '='
{
  // there is a formula
}
```

---

`substring(0,1)` gets the left symbol:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 4):

getFormula return true if there is a formula and false if it doesn't. There is no need to check the string for "=".

```
if (range.getFormula()) {
  ui.alert('has formula: ' + range.getFormula()); 
} else {
  ui.alert('no formula: ' + range.getFormula());  
}
```